# How to exclude sub-directory from cacls processing in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cacls

Suppose I have a directory `myDir` tree with many nested sub-directories. I grant full access to this directory with all its files and nested sub-directories to `myUser` with command:

```
cacls myDir /T /E /G myUser:F
```

So far, so good.

Now I have a sub-directory `myDir/A/B/C` which I would like to exclude from the `cacls` processing. That is, I would not like to grant `myUser` access to this sub-directory.

What would you suggest?

The simplest way is just to move this folder to another place before running `cacls` and move it back after that. Does it make sense?

Comment: Another solution is to add a second command that removes the `myuser` access from the folder.

Answer (score 3):

Inherited folder permissions are displayed as:

OI - Object inherit    - This folder and files. (no inheritance to subfolders)
CI - Container inherit - This folder and subfolders.
IO - Inherit only      - The ACE does not apply to the current file/directory

These can be combined as folllows:
(OI)(CI)                  This folder, subfolders, and files.
(OI)(CI)(IO)              Subfolders and files only.
     (CI)(IO)  Subfolders only.
(OI)    (IO)              Files only.

So BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)F means that both files and Subdirectories will inherit 'F' (Fullcontrol)
similarly (CI)R means Directories will inherit 'R' (Read folders only = List permission)

To actually change the inheritance of a folder/directory use `iCACLS /grant` or `iCACLs /deny`

Comment: The question was about how to make cacls not chane the permissions of a specific folder when processing the entire tree.
Permissions are set on each object, and inheritance is not automatic. Just setting a permission to be inherited doesn't change the permissions of any existing children - it basically just acts as the default ACL template to be used when creating new children.

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate a list of files to be processed and exclude the ones you don't want since CACLS doesn't allow filtering.

Here, I use "dir" to generate the list of files to process.
You could use "forfiles" as well.

(You can make the script more compact using pipes, but I used temporary files instead just to make it more clear).

```
@echo off
setlocal

set TMPFILE=%TEMP%\dirs.txt
set TMPFILE2=%TEMP%\dirs2.txt

@rem Generate the list of dir names to be processed
dir "%~1" /ad /s /b /p > %TMPFILE%

@rem Filter out the unwanted ones
findstr /i /v /C:"myDir\A\B\C" < %TMPFILE% > %TMPFILE2%

@rem And execute a command on each
for /F "delims=;" %%x in (%TMPFILE2%) do call :dostuff "%%x"

goto :EOF

:dostuff
    @rem do the directory itself
    cacls "%~1\ /E /G myUser:F

    @rem do the files
    cacls "%~1\*" /E /G myUser:F

    goto :EOF
```